# ¿Cómo leer estos operadores?

Tags: php

Como dice la pregunta tengo una duda sobre una línea del código en concreto que no sé como interpretarla aquí dejo el código completo , y más abajo la línea del código donde tengo dudas.

```
<?
$fecha1 = "11/15/1999“;
$fecha2 = "12/10/2000";
list ($mes1, $dia1, $anyo1) = explode ("/", $fecha1);
list ($mes2, $dia2, $anyo2) = explode ("/", $fecha2);
$instante1 = mktime (0, 0, 0, $mes1, $dia1, $anyo1);
$instante2 = mktime (0, 0, 0, $mes2, $dia2, $anyo2);
$diferencia = ($instante1 > $instante2) ?
($instante1 - $instante2) : ($instante2 - $instante1);
print(“La diferencia entre las fechas es “);
print(date ("Y“, $diferencia) – 1970);
print(" año(s), " . (date ("m", $diferencia) – 1));
print(“ mes(es) y " . (date ("d", $diferencia) – 1));
print(" día(s).)";
?>
```

**Aquí** es donde tengo dudas:
¿Cómo se leería o interpretaría?

```
  $diferencia = ($instante1 > $instante2) ?
($instante1 - $instante2) : ($instante2 - $instante1);
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es el equivalente a:

```
if ($instante1 > $instante2) {
     $diferencia = ($instante1 - $instante2);
} else {
     $diferencia = ($instante2 - $instante1);
}
```

Es el llamado [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Los paréntesis a la hora de asignar la variable $diferencia no serían necesarios, pero los he mantenido para que sea más fácil situarte.

Comment: Me sirvió , gracias!